# How to set custom gcc when using gdb

Tags: gcc, gdb

I have a program that is build with a different version of the `GCC` than the one on the system. When I try to debug the program using `GDB`, I am getting errors like

```
libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found 
libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found 
libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

But when I build and run the executable, I get no errors.

It seems that GDB is using a different libstdc++ than the one used when building. Is there a possibility to tell `GDB` what libs to use ?

At build, using Makefile, there are some variables set that say what `g++` to use, so it will be not the one on the system

Comment: if this is linux/unix,  set up PATH in env before invoking, or provide it on the command line when invoked, or in an environment setup file/wrapper, which invokes your build

Comment: How do you run the executable that is build with a different version of the GCC, when you get no errors?

Comment: Did you set any environment variables in your shell to run the executable?